# Migrate from keyboard input to UI buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble making the player move left and right idle when it stops running, with this script when the game starts the player will start animation state 1 and can run, but after the first run, the player can't run anymore.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;

public class UiPlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private BoxCollider2D coll;

    private Animator anim;
    private RaycastHit2D hit;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround;

    
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 14f;

    private bool TurnRight, TurnLeft, stop;

    private enum MovementState { Player_Idle, Player_Walk, Player_Jump, Player_Falling }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        coll = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
  
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        {
            
            
            if (TurnRight)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
                transform.localScale = new Vector2((Mathf.Sign(rb.velocity.x)), transform.localScale.y);
                UpdateAnimationState();

            }

            if (TurnLeft)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
                transform.localScale = new Vector2((Mathf.Sign(rb.velocity.x)), transform.localScale.y);
                UpdateAnimationState();
            }
            if (stop)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed = 0f, rb.velocity.y);
                UpdateAnimationState();
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {

            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);

        }
        UpdateAnimationState();
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {
        TurnRight = true;
        stop = false;
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        TurnLeft = true;
        stop = false;
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (rb.velocity.y == 0 && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
    }
    public void stopMoving()
    {
        TurnLeft = false;
        TurnRight = false;
        stop = true;
    }


    private void UpdateAnimationState()
    {
        MovementState state;

        if (moveSpeed > 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.Player_Walk;

        }
        else if (moveSpeed < 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.Player_Walk;

        }

        else
        {
            state = MovementState.Player_Idle;
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y > .1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.Player_Jump;
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y < -.1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.Player_Falling;
        }

        anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
    }
    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.BoxCast(coll.bounds.center, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, jumpableGround);
    }







}type here
```

I want to make the player move to the right and left but can also idle when not moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple movement, you don't need to define multiple variables with repetitive function. It is enough that the priorities are correct and each one is used in the correct place. In the following code, you can have the movement axis between -1 and 1 by getting `Input.GetAxis()`. Give this value to `rb.velocity.x` to fix the problem.

```cs
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var x = 0; // default xAxis always 0
    if (TurnRight) x++;
    if (TurnLeft) x--;

    if (IsGrounded() && rb.velocity.y < 0)
    {
        rb.velocity.y = 0;
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
        }
    }
    if (x != 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(x * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y); // multiply x axis to moveSpeed for final speed result
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(x, transform.localScale.y);
    }
    UpdateAnimationState();
}
```

Comment: Sorry. what i mean is i want to change player movement from wasd or arrow key to ui button. and also connected with movement animation.

Comment: @Yusril Again, it is not a problem. Pay attention to the answer update. If you are sure that the UI Buttons work correctly and return the events. The above code will fix the problem.